# How to use the AppSettings plugin on Xamarin? I want to be able to save what the user entered on EmailEntry

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

[image]How to use the AppSetting on Xamarin plugin. I installed it.  Now how to use it, I'm using Entry field with name on it to get the email address from the EmailEntry on xmlfile.

I tried some code on Main Page but the email entered is not getting save.

```
Settings.cs
namespace DrainLog.Utils
{

public static class Settings
{
private static ISettings AppSettings
{
get
{
return CrossSettings.Current;
}
}

#region Setting Constants

private const string LastEmailSettingsKey = "last_email_key";
private static readonly string SettingsDefault = string.Empty;

#endregion


public static string LastUsedEmail
{
get
{
return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(LastEmailSettingsKey, 
SettingsDefault);
}
set
{
AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(LastEmailSettingsKey, value);
}
}
}
}

MainPage
namespace DrainLog
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public static string item;

public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
drainquatity();
EmailAddress = DrainLog.Utils.Settings.LastUsedEmail;
}

public string emailAddress;

public string EmailAddress
{
get{return emailAddress;} 
set
{
emailAddress = value;
DrainLog.Utils.Settings.LastUsedEmail = value; 
}

private void EnterButton_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool isNameEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameEntry.Text);
bool isEmailEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailEntry.Text);

if (isNameEmpty || isEmailEmpty)
{

}
else
{
Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
}
}

}
}
}
```

I want to be able to save the email address that the user entered so when the user exits the app then re opens it. It's still there live it's save.

Comment: You should look at Xamarin.Essentials Secure Storage instead:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms

Comment: @SushiHangover is there any drawback using `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences` instead of SecureStorage in this case?

Comment: @EliasJohannes If you are storing user data (email, passwords. etc...) you really should be doing that in a secure manner. Esssential Preferences is great for app settings, color settings, frequency used files, etc... but those settings are not secure.

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you for the information! That's something to keep in mind. I was just asking because Preferences is extremely straight forward and easy to use, but in this case he should definitely be using Secure Storage then.

Comment: so if i want to save those user input on Main page which one should i use? preference, secure storage, or xam.plugin.settings?

Comment: @hypnocool Both is OK. Secure storage is more secure than preference.